# Member function pointer, pass function as argoument of a non member function

Tags: c++, pointers, member-functions

Is it possible to do something like this? Without using static functions or make `chordL` a member of `power`. I really don't understand how to do that, could it be not possible?

```
class power {
  double b;     

public:
  void set(double par){b=par}     

  double fun(double arg){
    return b*pow(arg,2); 
  } 

  double execute(double par1, double par2);
};

double chordL(power::*fm, double p1, double p2){      // it's not a member function
  return sqrt(pow(fm(p1)-fm(p2),2)+pow(p1-p2,2));  // clearly doesn't work! 
}

double power::execute(double par1, double par2){     // it's a member function
  double (power::*g)(double);
  g=&power::fun;
  return chordL(g,par1,par2);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that. A member function (that isn't declared `static`) has a special/hidden argument of `this`. If you have an object of the correct type, you can pass that along with the function, and call it using the obscure syntax needed for member function calls:

```
 double chordL(power* tp, double (power::*fm)(double), double p1, double p2)
 ...
     (tp->*fm)(p1); 


double power::execute(double par1, double par2){     // it's a member function
  double (power::*g)(double);
  g=&power::fun;
  return chordL(this, g,par1,par2);
}
```

Edit: added calling code, passing `this` to the chordL function, and swapped the order of the object and the function pointer from previous post - makes more sense to pass `this` as the first argument. And I fixed up the function pointer argument.

Comment: Ok! So I have to pass tp which is a class pointer. But how can I do this in the function execute? Cause I want to use chordL in execute which is a member of power!

Comment: Is `T::` supposed to refer to `power`? If so, you need to pass `this` along to chordL.

Comment: Yes, sorry! How to pass `this`? How could it be execute function? That's the point I don't understand!

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of `power` to call the function pointer on like this:

```
double chordL(T& instance, T::*fm, double p1, double p2){
    return sqrt(pow(instance.*fm(p1) - instance.*fm(p2), 2) + pow(p1 - p2, 2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling a member function, you need to specify the object it has to be called on. You need to pass `this` pointer to `chordL` as well, and call the function like this:

```
template<class T>
double chordL(T* t, double (T::*fn)(double), double p1, double p2)
{
    return sqrt(pow((t->*fn)(p1) - (t->*fn)(p2), 2) + pow(p1 - p2, 2));
}
```